# Finding Where on PO record has 2 different Ship Dates on multi-line order using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a bit of a strange situation.  We have Purchase Orders that can have 1 or more lines.  In case a purchase order has more than one line the requested ship dates should always be the same.  The issue is that we are finding instances where it has been entered wrong and we have different ship dates on different lines.  I have tried using `COUNT` but it just counts each line and returns 1 and in cases where both lines are the same it returns 2 so I can't compare a sum on the count.  Below is the query with a sample output of an incorrect result along with a correct result (both dates on the PO are the same).  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Query:

```
SELECT PO_NUMBER,PO_ITEM_NUMBER,PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE FROM VW_PO_ITEM

WHERE PO_NUMBER IN ('0284141253', '0284503082')

GROUP BY PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE, 
         PO_NUMBER, 
         PO_ITEM_NUMBER
```

Results:

```
PO_NUMBER  PO_ITEM_NUMBER                          PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE
---------- --------------------------------------- -----------------------
0284141253 1                                       2018-02-28 00:00:00.000
0284141253 2                                       2018-03-20 00:00:00.000
0284503082 1                                       2018-03-31 00:00:00.000
0284503082 2                                       2018-03-31 00:00:00.000

(4 row(s) affected)
```

I am wondering if some type of partition by may be needed?  If I `COUNT` the PO_ITEM and REQ_SHIP_DATE columns I get the below:

```
PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE        PO_NUMBER  COUNT_ITEM  COUNT_SHIP_DATE
----------------------- ---------- ----------- ---------------
2018-02-28 00:00:00.000 0284141253 1           1
2018-03-20 00:00:00.000 0284141253 1           1
2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 0284503082 2           2

(3 row(s) affected)
```

It seems as though because the ship dates are different it presents an issue, My thought would be to say where COUNT_SHIP_DATE =  1 but we do have more PO's that are only one line

Answer (score 1):

In my setup I just used dates, not full timestamp. If your timestamps have zeroed-out hh:mm:ss then you should be fine, otherwise you'll have to tweak the SQL:

```
select * from
(
select po_number, po_item_number, po_req_ship_date
    , row_number() over(partition by po_number, po_req_ship_date order by po_number, po_req_ship_date) as 'count_dates'
    , row_number() over(partition by po_number order by po_number) as 'count_items'
    , count(po_number) over(partition by po_number) as 'count_po_num'
from VW_PO_ITEM
)X
where count_po_num > 1
and count_dates > 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT PO_NUMBER, PO_ITEM_NUMBER
FROM VW_PO_ITEM
WHERE PO_NUMBER IN ('0284141253', '0284503082')
GROUP BY PO_NUMBER, PO_ITEM_NUMBER
HAVING MIN(PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE) <> MAX(PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE);
```

This returns the items on the order that have inconsistent ship dates.  Note:  This ignores `NULL` values.  The logic can be adapted to handle them as well.

Comment: that seems to return no results where I would have expected it to return the incorrect PO.

Comment: @user3496218 . . . Perhaps your "dates" have time components, and you need to remove those for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that does the trick - finds any PO's that have more than one unique ship date and by default must be multi-line PO's - thanks for the help and ideas some stuff to use in the future (note I have joined to an employee table):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT I.PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE) AS '# OF REQ_SHIP_DATES', I.PO_NUMBER, E.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME [EMPLOYEE]

FROM   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_ITEM I
JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED..SCM_PO_Employee_Name E
ON     I.PO_NUMBER = E.PO_NUMBER

WHERE DEL_INDICATOR <> 'L'
AND   PO_BALANCE_QUANTITY > 0
GROUP BY I.PO_NUMBER, E.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT I.PO_REQ_SHIP_DATE) > 1;
```